# HTML video is rotated in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have a video that gets rotated in Chrome but not in Firefox. And I have video metadata doesn't tell anything about video orientation why could this happened?

**Chrome video is rotated**
[image: Chrome video rotated]

**Firefox video is not rotated**
[image: Firefox video is not rotated]

**VLC video metadata**
[image: VLC video metadata]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `ffmpeg -i` returns

```
Side data: displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
```

so had to re-transcode with `rotation=0`